# Python3 Portscanner does not recognize open Port 80, but Port 22 always

Tags: python, port

I was writing a small Portscanner, but it only recognizes open port 22, not port 80 although it's open and a webserver is there. Any one knows how to fix this?
Code goes below:

```
"""
PortScanner v0.01
"""
import socket
import threading
import sys
import time
def CheckIfOpen(ip,port):
    target = (ip,int(port))
    try:
        s = socket.create_connection(target)
        t = s.recv(1024)
        if t:
            open('open','a').write(ip+":"+str(port)+"\n")
            print("Port: "+str(port)+" open on IP: "+ip+"!\n")
    except:
        pass
if sys.argv[4]:
    threads = int(sys.argv[4])
else:
    threads = 100
start = sys.argv[1].split(".")
end = sys.argv[2].split(".")
if int(end[3]) != 255:
    end[3] = int(end[3])+1
else:
    if int(end[2]) != 255:
        end[2] = int(end[2])+1
        end[3] = 0
    else:
        if int(end[1]) != 255:
            end[1] = int(end[1])+1
            end[2] = 0
            end[3] = 0
        else:
            if int(end[0]) != 255:
                end[0] = int(end[0])+1
                end[1] = 0
                end[2] = 0
                end[3] = 0
end = str(end[0])+"."+str(end[1])+"."+str(end[2])+"."+str(end[3])
current = str(start[0])+"."+str(start[1])+"."+str(start[2])+"."+str(start[3])
try:
    ports = sys.argv[3].split(",")
except:
    ports = sys.argv[3]
while(current != end):
    for port in ports:
        if threading.active_count() <= int(threads):
            T = threading.Thread(target=CheckIfOpen,args=(current,int(port),))
            T.start()
        else:
            time.sleep(0.2)
            T = threading.Thread(target=CheckIfOpen,args=(current,int(port),))
            T.start()
    progress = current.split(".")
    if int(progress[3]) != 255:
        progress[3] = int(progress[3])+1
    else:
        if int(progress[2]) != 255:
            progress[2] = int(progress[2])+1
            progress[3] = 0
        else:
            if int(end[1]) != 255:
                progress[1] = int(progress[1])+1
                progress[2] = 0
                progress[3] = 0
            else:
                if int(progress[0]) != 255:
                    progress[0] = int(progress[0])+1
                    progress[1] = 0
                    progress[2] = 0
                    progress[3] = 0
    current = str(progress[0])+"."+str(progress[1])+"."+str(progress[2])+"."+str(progress[3])
T.join()
print("Scan finished!\n")
exit()
```

is the way i'm forcing the connection wrong? i just made this up since i was bored, but maybe someone can help me. :)

i wrote this in python3, and also compiled it using cython, but there is no way to get other open ports than port 22, neither on lan, nor on wan. :(
also, it hung up now, while on finishing the port scan :/

edit:\ fixxed it by not retrieving a message from socket, working code below:

```
"""
PortScanner v0.01
"""
import socket
import threading
import sys
import time
def CheckIfOpen(ip,port):
    target = (ip,int(port))
    try:
        socket.create_connection(target,1.5)
        open('open','a').write(ip+":"+str(port)+"\n")
        print("Port: "+str(port)+" open on IP: "+ip+"!\n")
    except:
        print("Port: "+str(port)+" closed on IP: "+ip+"!\n")
if sys.argv[4]:
    threads = int(sys.argv[4])
else:
    threads = 100
start = sys.argv[1].split(".")
end = sys.argv[2].split(".")
if int(end[3]) != 255:
    end[3] = int(end[3])+1
else:
    if int(end[2]) != 255:
        end[2] = int(end[2])+1
        end[3] = 0
    else:
        if int(end[1]) != 255:
            end[1] = int(end[1])+1
            end[2] = 0
            end[3] = 0
        else:
            if int(end[0]) != 255:
                end[0] = int(end[0])+1
                end[1] = 0
                end[2] = 0
                end[3] = 0
end = str(end[0])+"."+str(end[1])+"."+str(end[2])+"."+str(end[3])
current = str(start[0])+"."+str(start[1])+"."+str(start[2])+"."+str(start[3])
try:
    ports = sys.argv[3].split(",")
except:
    ports = sys.argv[3]
while(current != end):
    for port in ports:
        if threading.active_count() <= int(threads):
            T = threading.Thread(target=CheckIfOpen,args=(current,int(port),))
            T.start()
        else:
            time.sleep(0.2)
            T = threading.Thread(target=CheckIfOpen,args=(current,int(port),))
            T.start()
    progress = current.split(".")
    if int(progress[3]) != 255:
        progress[3] = int(progress[3])+1
    else:
        if int(progress[2]) != 255:
            progress[2] = int(progress[2])+1
            progress[3] = 0
        else:
            if int(end[1]) != 255:
                progress[1] = int(progress[1])+1
                progress[2] = 0
                progress[3] = 0
            else:
                if int(progress[0]) != 255:
                    progress[0] = int(progress[0])+1
                    progress[1] = 0
                    progress[2] = 0
                    progress[3] = 0
    current = str(progress[0])+"."+str(progress[1])+"."+str(progress[2])+"."+str(progress[3])
T.join()
print("Scan finished!\n")
exit()
```

Comment: Right, a web server is not going to send anything until it receives a properly-formatted command.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for multi-threaded port scan

```
import socket
import threading
from queue import Queue

target = "1.1.1.1"
#target = "192.168.1.130"

queue = Queue()
open_ports = []

def portscan(port):
    try:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.connect((target,port))
        return True
    except:
        return False

def fill_queue(port_list):
    for port in port_list:
        queue.put(port)

def worker():
    while not queue.empty():
        port = queue.get()
        if portscan(port):
            print("Port {} is open ! ".format(port))
            open_ports.append(port)

port_list = range(1,65530)
fill_queue(port_list)

thread_list = []

for t in range(50000):  #thread count
    thread = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    thread_list.append(thread)

for thread in thread_list:
    thread.start()

for thread in thread_list:
    thread.join()

print("Open ports are :" , open_ports)
```

Comment: thank you, but i made it scanning ip-ranges for my lan, so, your single ip solution is not what i expected to use, nevermind, i already found a working solution, like i stated above. anyways, thank you again :)